# ubuntu login once boot process

Tags: login

I can't launch ubuntu
Once the reboot process was terminated
A login and a password was asked to me
I've tried every combination
None is working
Now I'm blocked front of a black screen
Can you please tell me where to find those login and password ?

Comment: When Ubuntu is installed, it asks you to create a username and password. This username and password are used to set up a user account on the system. Do you remember what username and password you might have chosen when it was installed?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for relying but I've tried any times to enter the login and password created during the installation, it keeps refusing them

Comment: If your computer is set to automatically log in when it boots up, you could just hold the power button until it turns off, and then power it on again.

Comment: Done it many times, even relaunch another install, reenter login and pass but they aren't still recognized as correct

Answer (score 0):

This help page details the methods that you can use to fix your login issue: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html

> Restart your computer, and hold down Shift during bootup to get into the Grub menu.
>
> Press the down arrow on your keyboard to highlight the line that ends with the words 'recovery mode', then press Enter.
>
> Your computer will now begin the boot process. After a few moments, a Recovery Menu will appear. Use your down arrow key to highlight root and press Enter.
>
> At the # symbol, type:
>
> `passwd username`, where username is the username of the account you're changing the password for.
>
> You will be prompted to enter a new UNIX password, and to confirm the new password.
>
> Then type:
>
> `# reboot`

Comment: It wasn't any login problem in fact

Comment: I've downloaded a new version and chek it properly with the sums soft

Comment: Everything is fine now